# Creating a separate files for just CSF Stories

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

My current storybook file looks like the following:

**Button.stories.js:**

```js
import { Button } from './Button';

export default {
  title: 'Example/Button',
  component: Button,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  argTypes: {
    backgroundColor: { control: 'color' },
  },
};

export const Primary = {
  args: {
    primary: true,
    label: 'Button',
  },
};

export const Secondary = {
  args: {
    label: 'Button',
  },
};

export const Large = {
  args: {
    size: 'large',
    label: 'Button',
  },
};

export const Small = {
  args: {
    size: 'small',
    label: 'Button',
  },
};
```

How can I create a separate file for just my Stories and then import it into my `Button.stories.js` file? I'm trying to do something like the below. Storybook does not work when I try this, because when I run storybook, no stories are created.

**Button.examples.js:**

```js
import { Button } from './Button';

export const Primary = {
  args: {
    primary: true,
    label: 'Button',
  },
};

export const Secondary = {
  args: {
    label: 'Button',
  },
};

export const Large = {
  args: {
    size: 'large',
    label: 'Button',
  },
};

export const Small = {
  args: {
    size: 'small',
    label: 'Button',
  },
};
```

**Button.stories.js:**

```js
import { Button } from './Button';
export * from './Button.examples';

export default {
  title: 'Example/Button',
  component: Button,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  argTypes: {
    backgroundColor: { control: 'color' },
  },
};
```

**To Reproduce:**
Go to [this repo / branch](https://github.com/jimmy-e/storybook-fn-debug/tree/how_to_export), run `npm install`, and then `npm run storybook`.

Comment: it's not clear exactly what you mean by "Storybook doesn't work" - but the obvious thing wrong with your second code sample is that the `text.stories.ts` file no longer actually exports the stories...

Comment: Thanks. How do I get it to export those stories from another file?

Comment: @RobinZigmond, please see the above edits with a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v7 of storybook, you need to export stories as the following:

`export { Primary, Secondary, Large, Small } from './Button.examples';`

Please see [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/21734#issuecomment-1479951389) for further detail.